# idiomatic way of doing a C# TryGetValue in C++ with restriction of using only std::unique_ptr<T>

Tags: c#, c++, c++11

In C#, or I suppose in any managed language you can do the following:

```
List<T> value;
if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    value = new List<T>();
    myDictionary.Add(key, value);
}

value.Add(new T());

// and so on ...
```

In C++, I have restricted myself to use `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>`, but I want to replicate that what I did in C#.

However, I don't want to lose the safety C++11 provides me here, i.e. I don't want to do a `.get()` on the pointer. I'm looking for a way that the compiler can do that for me, without me typing it (and therefore avoiding a mistake).

Is there some trick here? I couldn't find anything obvious.

EDIT Here's what I have, but this has an extra hash calculation, the `.find()` is one, `myDictionary[value]` is the second, and there's another one of those to do the get():

```
std::vector<T> *rawPtr;
auto iter = myDictionary.find(value);
if (iter == myDictionary.end())
{
    myDictionary[value] = std::make_unique<std::vector<T>>();
    rawPtr = myDictionary[value].get();
}

// work with RawPtr in the local function as a read only thing
```

Comment: Not sure what `myDictionary` is, but with C++ maps it would be `myDictionary[key].Add(whatever);` Not sure what the relevance of `unique_ptr` is either.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I edited my question. myDictionary[key] would call the default cctor of std::vector<T> so it in fact adds the value.

Comment: Any reason you store unique_ptr to vector instead of vectors? It only seems to complicate things.

Comment: myDictionary is not allocated on the stack, so it's somewhere else.

Comment: also that vector will get pretty big ... like millions or entries, so i don't want to keep bringing down the copy.

Comment: About "not allocated on the stack", doesn't make any difference re. storing vectors directly. About the vectors being big, doesn't matter, you don't have to copy them if you don't want to. I think you're over-complicating things.

Comment: Your C# and C++ code disagree over whether the new list/vector should be added to the dictionary.

Comment: @hvd: fixing. I intended to add.

Comment: @MikeMB: I would love a reference version.

Comment: @hvd: but now I see your point, if you were trying to make one ... the C# one also has two dictionary lookups ... rather more accurately hash calculations.

Comment: @halivingston That was the point I initially tried to make, but I deleted that version of my comment because your C++ version has three lookups (get, set, get), so it's still more than your C# version.

Comment: What exactly is myDictionary and do you want the newly created vector to be part of it after this function?

Comment: myDictionary is some std::unordered_map allocated somewhere on the heap.

Comment: @hvd: true, so yeah there is one extra hash calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the semantic you want, but if you want to add an entry that is not already there, the following code gives you what you want with a single lookup:

```
std::unordered_map<KeyType,std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>> myDictionary;

std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>& entry = myDictionary[key]; 
if (!entry){
    entry = std::make_unique<std::vector<T>>();
}

std::vector<T>& valueList = *entry;
valueList.push_back(newValue);
// and so on ...
```

Also, as @juanchopanza noted in the comments, most likely there is no reason to use `unique_ptr`s at all and you can just write:

```
std::unordered_map<KeyType,std::vector<T>> myDictionary;

std::vector<T>& valueLst = myDictionary[key];
valueList.push_back(newValue);

//and so on
```

This saves you a separate heap allocation for each new entry (which are afaik much more expensive in c++ than in c#)

Comment: thanks, this is a good one. I wonder if this calls two ctors for std::vector<T> .. I think it does.

Comment: @halivingston: No, why should it?

Comment: wouldn't myDictionary[key] call the default ctor .. otherwise what is it assigning?

Comment: @halivingston: In the first version (with the `unique_ptr`), `myDictionary[key]` will call the default constructor of `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>`, which just creates a `nullptr`. The only point, where a new vector is created is inside make_unique.

Comment: And even if it where: Default constructing a `std::vector` means zeroing out three pointers, so the cost would be absolutely negligible compared to everything else that is going on here.

Comment: thanks @MikeMB .. I agree, just want to make sure my c++11 semantics are rock solid :)